# Is there any option to get focus back on the same element after blur

Tags: jquery

Is there any option to get focus back on the same element after blur (based on some calculation).
    This is my jQuery:-

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").blur(function (e) {
//code       
$(this).focus();  
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3asZC/4/

Comment: @Zubairsadiq That is a different kind of blur.

Comment: why do you want this effect ? for showing error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using `setTimeout()`. Note you may block the user from moving about in the form if you do this improperly and if the next field is a text or textarea too, you will start a loop

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").blur(function (e) {
  var id = this.id; // or save $(this) in a var
  setTimeout(function() { $("#"+id).focus();}, 100);
});
```

Comment: The thing is that if next focused element is an input (text) or textarea, it makes it buggy   https://jsfiddle.net/arj41s3u/

Comment: thanks @mplungjan, I was doing it wrong, was using `$(this)` in anonymous function;  now stored `$(this)`  into `$this`, now working fine

Comment: Hence the var id in mine

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, so you should use a workaround using setTimeout function

```
$("input[type='text'],textarea").blur(function (e) {
//code       
   var $text = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){ $text.focus(); }, 0);

});
```

Comment: I fail to see the difference between this and mine except I give 100 millisecs to focus.

Comment: @mplungjan except your code need input to have an ID otherwise won't work

Comment: True. I was considering that.. Yours will also loop if the next field is text or textarea like mine does

Comment: @mplungjan, sure but in the question he said  _based on some calculation_ so i assume he won't trigger focus in any case